# Error handling in Eiffel and Rescue clause

Tags: exception, error-handling, eiffel

Is writing one rescue clause at the end of a program to end the program in Eiffel enough to handle exceptions such as pre, postconditions or invariant violations in any of the routines written in the program? Or should I write rescue clause for every function having pre and postconditions to handle exceptions?

I have read [Eiffel documentation on error handling](https://www.eiffel.org/doc/solutions/Exception_Mechanism) but I couldn't figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on your expectations. The method is as follows:

1. Precondition violations are reported to the caller. They indicate a bug in the caller. If bugs are expected or possible in the callers, you can catch and handle them in the callers.
2. Postcondition violations are reported to the callee. They indicate bugs in the callee. The callee can catch and handle them if such bugs are expected.
3. Class invariants are established at object creation. If they are violated by the creation procedure or after the execution of a procedure used in a qualified call, they indicate a bug in the callee and can be handled like postcondition violations. Otherwise, they indicate more complex issue involving object dependencies. It could be handled by the caller, but most likely it would be next to impossible to restore correct object state.

In all cases, assertion violations mean a program bug and whether and how it should be caught and handled depends on your needs. E.g., it's possible to do the handling somewhere between the problematic code and the root procedure.

Comment: My question actually implies that, If one precondition fails, program totally fails, giving a precondition violation, so it must go to the rescue statement?(Is my assumption correct about the flow of the program here?) where we just output the invalid statement or retry again, so I again thought  writing only one rescue statement makes sense rather than writing it in all routines.

Comment: @AkashTadwai An author of a library could think "the code is not well-tested yet, I'd better put a rescue clause to catch any issue, and report the failure using the library API rather than letting the whole application to crash". An author of another library could think the same. And an author of the application that uses both libraries could think about catching exceptions to let the user do something else (e.g., so to save his work before terminating the application). That would end up in multiple rescue clauses in several places. So, it really depends on the development process.

Comment: One more question, is there a way to run .e files(Eiffel projects) by checking all the contracts through command line? ec <filename>.e just ignores all the pre, post conditions and invariants written in file, suppose if we want to terminate, for invalid inputs and I wrote something through rescue will it be executed? is there any way to do run Eiffel file through command line checking all conditions or we must need Eiffel studio for that?

Comment: @AkashTadwai EiffelStudio provides a convenient and robust way to edit project settings. The [format](https://www.eiffel.com/developers/xml/) of the file where the settings are recorded changes over time, so it's advisory to use the project settings dialog to set assertion monitoring level. Still, you can edit associated `.ecf` file yourself. As of time of writing, you can make sure that inside the corresponding element `target` there is an element `option` with `<assertions precondition="true" postcondition="true" check="true" invariant="true" loop="true" supplier_precondition="true"/>`.